# Parse html nested list to perl array

Tags: perl, xml-parsing, html-parsing

Input data: (some nested list with links )

```
<ul>
    <li><a>1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>11</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>111</a></li>
                    <li><a>112</a></li>
                    <li><a>113</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>1131</a></li>
                        <li><a>1132</a></li>
                        <li><a>1133</a></li>
                    </ul></li>
                    <li><a>114</a></li>
                    <li><a>115</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a>12</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>121</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>1211</a></li>
                        <li><a>1212</a></li>
                        <li><a>1213</a></li>
                    </ul></li>
                    <li><a>122</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Output array of strings:

```
 1,11,111
 1,11,112
 1,11,113,1131
 1,11,113,1132
 1,11,113,1133
 1,11,114
 1,11,115
 1,12,121,1211
 1,12,121,1212
 1,12,121,1213
 1,12,122
```

Full path with text of  element which in

without childs.

What I tried: 
1. XML::SAX::ParserFactory

https://gist.github.com/7266638 Alot of problem here. How to detect if li last, how to save path etc. I think its bad way.

1. Its totaly not a regexp, cos in real life example html much worse. Alot of tags, divs, spans etc

Dom? But how?

Comment: I don't understand why `1131`, `1132` and `1133` appear after `113` when they are at same level in the tree.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I place wrong tag /li

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with `XML::Twig` module. It saves all text from `<a>` elements and only prints them when there is no child `<ul>` under one of `<li>` elements.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my (@li);

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
        twig_handlers => {
                'a' => sub {
                        if ( $_->prev_elt('li') ) { 
                                push @li, $_->text;
                        }   
                },  
                'li' => sub {
                        unless ( $_->children('ul') ) { 
                                printf qq|%s\n|, join q|,|, @li;
                        }   
                        pop @li;
                },  
        },  
)->parsefile( shift );
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl xmlfile
```

That yields:

```
1,11,111
1,11,112
1,11,113,1131
1,11,113,1132
1,11,113,1133
1,11,114
1,11,115
1,12,121,1211
1,12,121,1212
1,12,121,1213
1,12,122
```

Comment: Thank you! Its awesome. Also XML::Twig - is good point for me.